# SSRS in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services

I was trying to implement SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2010. I have searched many sites regarding this situation. But i haven't get any solution for this. Is there any way i can develop SSRS reports in VS2010? Pls help me for this?

Thanks

Comment: I think your answer is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/78bd6eb6-9d14-48e2-80eb-8c8e66b52534: "In Visual Studio 2010, it currently only supports developing local reports (.rdlc)... To develop a SSRS 2008 project, please use Visual Studio 2008."  The same link suggests that *maybe* you can update your MSVS2010 to SP1, and install the "BIDS" portion of MSSQL.

Comment: @paulsm4: Yes i have my SSRS reports developed using VS2008. how can i migrate from rdl into rdlc for VS2010.

Comment: Please read the link I cited and see if you can make the updates that worked for the other folks who posted: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/78bd6eb6-9d14-48e2-80eb-8c8e66b52534/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop .rdl reports in Visual studio 2010/2012 now.

It requires VS 10 with SP1, SQL Server Data Tools installation (some workaround for VS 10/12), and then SQL Server 2012 for the Reporting Services and Data Tools.

[Are SSRS Reports supported in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333459/is-there-any-inbuilt-localization-resources-support-in-ssrs-using-visual-studio)